# NVD3.js - x axis categories not displaying properly for lineplusbar

Tags: svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'd like the axis to read "1x", "2x", 3x". In the other graph types, the x value it correctly taken from the value, but this one seems different. I know if I comment out

```
.x(function(d,i) { return i });
```

The graph's display no longer functions properly. I could add in

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',f')(d+1)+"x" });
```

But that is a cheat that wouldn't work if the x axis was some other string.

Code: https://github.com/tvinci/webs/blob/gh-pages/lineplusbar.html

Example: http://tvinci.github.io/webs/lineplusbar.html

Code from page:

```
  nv.addGraph(function() {
     //var testdata = exampleData();
     var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
           .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
           //if this is commented out, the graph does not display properly
           .x(function(d,i) { return i });
     //this is the cheat I use to show the correct X axis
     //chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',f')(d+1)+"x" });
     chart.y1Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
     chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

     //forces the chart to start at 0
     // if you set this to [0,100] and your data's domain is -10 to 110, the domain will be [-10,110]
     chart.lines.forceY([0]);

     d3.select('#chart svg').datum(eval("overview_data")).transition().duration(500).call(chart);
      d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar").style("fill", function(d, i){return i > 50 ? "red":"blue";});
     nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
```

Data:

```
var overview_data=[
     { "key" : "Achieved" , "bar": true,"values" : [ [ "1x" , 30] , [ "2x" , 70] , [ "3x" , 200] ]} ,
     { "key" : "Required" , "values" : [ [ "1x" , 50] , [ "2x" , 100] , [ "3x" , 150] ]}
    ].map(function(series) {series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });return series;});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The only trick I see is not to use d3.format() if you don't need it. Just do this:

```
 chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return (d+1)+"x" });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/RqvJR/

Answer (score 0):

@chris - That's my cheat. :) It won't work if the x value changes to something like "Monday".

I was able to figure out that I can just feed the index to my data object to pull out the correct value.

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {return overview_data[0].values[d].x; });
```